# Banach spaces with $d(X,Y) = 1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We recall that the Banach-Mazur distance between two isomorphic Banach spaces is given by $d(X,Y) = \inf \{ \|T\| \|T^{-1}\| : T$ is an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y\}$.

It is a classical result that we can find two infinite dimensional Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $d(X,Y) = 1$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not isometric.

(very briefly, if we take $X = \left( \oplus_n \ell_{p_n}^2 \right)$ with $p_n$ dense in $(1,2]$ and $Y = X \oplus \ell_1^2$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ such that $\|T\| \|T^{-1}\| < 1+\epsilon$. However since $X$ is strictly convex and $Y$ is not, then there is no isometric isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$.)

The above example can be generalized to $\ell_p$ with some knowledge of the Jordan-von Neumann constant - indeed if $p < 2$ taking $p_n$ dense in $(p,2]$ letting $X = \left( \oplus_n \ell_{p_n}^2 \right)_2$ and $Y = X \oplus \ell_p^2$ one can show that $d(X,Y) = 1$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not isometrically isomorphic. (If $p>2$ then you can take $p_n$ dense in $[2,p)$. I'm unaware if appears in the literature anywhere, if anyone is interested I can fill in the details.)

These examples seem to fit into the same category of examples, and this is essentially related to 'convexity' or some notion of '$p$-convexity'.

Is anyone aware of any 'fundamentally different' example? This is not a particularly well posed question, so for a very specific question:

Are there two Banach space $X$ and $Y$ for which $d(X,Y) = 1$, $X$ and $Y$ are not isometrically isomorphic, and the proof that $X$ and $Y$ are not isometrically isomorphic is unrelated to concepts of convexity? The kind of thing I am thinking of is an algebraic obstruction to isometric isomorphism, or perhaps related to the action of the spaces on others.

Comment: It is not about convexity really but just about having two different countable sequences of norms dense in each other. Once you get that, you can play the proof game in any way you want. For instance, you can repeat one norm three or more times in one of the sequence but not in the other one creating a non-commutative group of automorphisms for the resulting sum space, etc. So the words "fundamentally different" should rather mean "non-decomposable into sums of that kind" in some strong sense.